# Is RIM Blackberry can auto choose correct image?

Tags: blackberry, resources, naming-conventions, resolution

For Android folder, there was `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-hdpi` and etc.

In Blackberry folder, i don't know the folder naming convention to handle difference screen resolution. `Screen sizes can be placed into two categories, high resolution and low resolution`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no such mechanism in BlackBerry (I'm talking about Java APIs, don't know how would it be on WebWorks or BB10).

But you definitely should create a mechanism of your own. You'll have to manage different screen sizes in almost every project, so it is worth coding. I'm currently doing that in several projects. The idea is to create subpackages inside res/img package (like, for instance, res/img/320 for screen widths of 320 px). Then you paste the correct image in each subpackage, as you would do in Android. Last, code an `ImageManager` class whose main purpose is to serve all image request from every other class in the app:

- At app startup (or at each bitmap request, if you are going to allow screen rotation) you get the current screen resolution calling `Display.getWidth();`
- When a image is requested, `ImageManager` searchs for a folder inside res/img with the proper name:

  `Inputstream is = ImageManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/img/<current resolution>/someimage.png");`
- If such directory exists, get the image:

  ```
      byte[] rawFileData = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
      EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(rawFileData, 0, rawFileData.length);
  ```

In case you don't have a directory for the current screen resolution, you could:

1. Provide a fallback directory such as /img/common, with images big enough so that they do not lose quality when scaled down. Then get the image as usual and scale proportionally to the current resolution. The new methods added in `Bitmap` class in OS 5 can do this in no time with different scaling options and good performance.
2. Get the images for the nearest resolution for which a custom directory exists (i.e.: if current res is 360, but /img/360 does not exist, get images from /img/320).

Finally, a pro tip: You could code a façade to `ImageManager` with shorter class and methods names, and make it a Singleton. That way, you could type:

```
R.drawable("someimage.png");
```

Which is pretty similar to Android syntax.

Comment: If you have efficient build process and efficient OTA distribution. I would suggest to split builds for different resolution. It will simplify code, shrink cod size (faster download and install) but will give more in support.

Comment: can I have the sample of whole project folder that support difference screen resolution.

Comment: @Eugen Martynov I'd love to do that instead, but unfortunately I have to provide a single cod to clients.

Comment: @Alan Lai Good Try XD. I'm sorry I can't. The code is propietary.

Comment: @Eugen Martynov Another thing that comes to my mind is what about BlackBerry App World? Does it have a system similar to Android's, so that devices only download the correct version for their resolution?

Comment: @MisterSmith there is no resolutions. But you could specify certain devices which is almost the same. Except that you need to find yourself their resolutions and hope that OS update doesn't change to much.

Answer (score 0):

In blackberry, We don't have the option to kept low and high resolution images sapareately as like android. Instead of that, We have to create the custom folder under the resource folder and then have to kept the images in single or a multiple folder based on your needs.